# How can I draw a wavelet system in Latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-pic

I'm trying to draw a figure to introduce a wavelet transform system as follows. I used tikzpicture to draw a lot of block nodes and connected them using arrow. However, I am struggling in the left-most and right-most part of the picture. Specifically, I don't know how to neither creat a "point", where some text in the left side or right side of this point, or make sure this "point" is between the two rows.

[image]

Comment: Could you add a minimal code?

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to TeX-SE! With forest it is easy (but of course I did not punch in texts from your screen shot). Also adding the annotations is easy, I did this only for `rows` but once you have sufficiently many levels you can add the analogous statements for those, too.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}

    \begin{forest}
for tree={grow'=east,l sep+=4mm,s sep+=2mm,
    draw, semithick,forked edges,edge={-latex},
   before typesetting nodes={
    where level=0{draw=none}{},
    where level=1{label=above:\emph{rows}}{},
    where level=4{label=above:\emph{columns}}{},
    % you can add the other labels at the respective levels analogously
    where n children=0{draw=none}{}
                            }
                }
[Start
    [A
        [A1 
          [A1a
            [A11 [A11a]]
            [A12 [A12a]]
          ] 
        ]
        [A2
          [A2a
            [A21 [A21a]]
            [A22 [A22a]]
          ]
         ]
    ]
    [B
        [B1
          [B1a
            [B11 [B11a]]
            [B12 [B12a]]
          ]
        ]
        [B2
          [B2a
            [B11 [B11a]]
            [B12 [B12a]]
          ]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! By your influence I am trying to learn the forest method instead of creating nodes in tikz. Another interesting question is, what if I would like to add some texts above the line after A1a? Since the line after A1a is too short, I guess I need to lengthen the line after A1a first, and add some texts above it then?

Comment: @mgcy You do not have to lengthen the text. One out of many possibilities is to replace `where n children=0{draw=none}{}` by `where n children=0{draw=none,label={[anchor=south west]above left:some long
 text}}{}`. There are many other possibilities.

Comment: I tired your solution but it doesn't look descent. It is my bad for the ambiguous description. I would better attach  a picture. The picture is above in the original question.

Comment: @mgcy No, you should not attach a picture but some code that at least contains all the relevant texts. Why do you think anyone is excited to type in texts from a screen shot? It is fine if you use my above code for that. (The rules of this site would suggest that you accept this answer and use the code for a follow-up question because I believe that what you are asking now is not part of the original question.)